# jwrapper runtime error BadDrawable

Tags: jwrapper

I built a jwrapper offline file.

./applicationXX-linux64-offline

Files get unpacked but it stops with a runtime error at the splash screen.

```
[HttpDownloader] RGB - ALPHA Image found

[Splash] Got image of size: 600 x 260
+13       [Extractor] Showing splash
[Splash] showSplash()

[Splash] Creating splash thread

X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)

  Major opcode of failed request:  70 (X_PolyFillRectangle)

  Resource id in failed request:  0x4000005

  Serial number of failed request:  31

  Current serial number in output stream:  49
```

Any ideas ?

Gentoo Linux 64 Bit.

Thank you!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it might be an issue with your splash PNG file. Are the images that you specify in the config all valid?  Could you try opening and re-saving them with another image app and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue under 32bit Slackware. Deleting the cached data in ~/.JWrapper for that application fixed it, although the error originally triggered the first time I ever ran it (although the app doesn't run, I guess JWrapper doesn't support console apps?).